# How to implement the spotlight search inside application for iphone /ipad development

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, search

Can any one get me idea in implementing the spotlight search inside application for iphone /ipad development?

Comment: Siva, what are you trying to achieve? (1) To get the iOS Spotlight search search within your app? (2) Or to implement a search bar like spotlight? I'm asking since the answer below seems to answer #2, and not #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store all the search items in an array. When the user start searching(use [UISearchBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)), code in the following delegate

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
     //Find all the value matches your searchText
     //Display them in a tableView.
}
```